# djangocms: command not found

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I installed django cms by this command

```
$ sudo pip3 install django-cms
```

the installation is completed and returns this:

```
Requirement already satisfied: django-cms in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: django-classy-tags>=0.7.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from django-cms)
Requirement already satisfied: django-formtools>=1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from django-cms)
Requirement already satisfied: Django<2.0,>=1.8 in /home/amir/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from django-cms)

Requirement already satisfied: djangocms-admin-style>=1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from django-cms)
Requirement already satisfied: django-sekizai>=0.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from django-cms)
Requirement already satisfied: django-treebeard>=4.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from django-cms)
```

However, when I want to use djangocms it returns

```
djangocms: command not found
```

I use Python 3.6 and django 1.9.5 (I know it is an old version but the project belongs to my company and they use this version).

Comment: According to [this](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/reference/cli.html) the command is not `djangocms` but `cms` instead. Try that.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty to reformat your question. For example I removed the python3 tag, since this question is not version-specific. Using the general python tag you will reach a lot more people.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/introduction/install.html
My guess is you forgot to run: pip install djangocms-installer
I'm guessing that because I did that too. I installed pip install django-cms, then wondered why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this and got it solved. Afterwards my palm went to my face because I was like "duh" lol. Oh well. Here is what the issue was for me and how I fixed it.

```
cd ~/
ls -al
```

This should give you the files and folders in your user directory. (NOTE: I use AWS instances so most of the time my user will be bitnami unless I change it. Your user will be different.) What you want to look for are .bashrc or .profile or both. I updated both. Use whatever text editor you wish to open that/those files

```
nano .bashrc
```

and/or

```
nano .profile
```

Usually at the top of these files you will have something like

```
PATH=/opt/bitnami/apache/bin:/opt/bitnami/apache2/bin:/opt/bitnami/common/bin:
export PATH
```

The djangocms script is installed in the **/home/bitnami/.local/bin** folder. You will want to add this path to the PATH variable in your .bashrc and .profile files. (NOTE: If you don't use bitnami stacks your path will be slightly different. You can't just copy and paste from here) Now save these files.

Here is where my palm went to my forehead. I went back to my django projects directory and issued the command

```
djangocms -f -p . projectname
```

and received

```
djangocms: Command not found
```

I forgot that you have to reload this information into your session or log out and log back in for these changes to take effect. So either log out/reboot or if you don't want to log out you can issue the following command

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

After that everything should work fine. If not there were probably errors with your installation. Refer to the [djangocms documentation](https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/install.html) regarding installation and python compatibility. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the installer package:

```
pip install djangocms-installer
```

You will now find it in `bin/djangocms` in your environment.

Beware: currently the installer is for django 3.1 and django-cms 3.8
So for the current django-cms 4.1.0rc4 you have to go the manual way.